# Handle All Notification With different Message Android

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

In my project I have one activity, a broadcast receiver to check the notification received and the firebase notification services. I am creating notification with different ids, but I am setting message of last received message. What I want is to handle the body of all the notification separately, So when I am tap on particular one notification it will return the exact body which is regarding to that one. How can I get the body separately? Or how can I store that notifications so that I can handle it when I need it..

Thanks in advance guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

What you can do is you can store notification in **sqlite** database when it arrives. so whenever you need it you can get it from database.
Just create table **Notification** with fields like

**notification** = notification unique id

**message**  = notification body

**type** = notification type(if you have different type of notification)

This way you can handle notification when you need it.

Comment: no i have only one typo notification like global.. but in that topic message i have to manage all notification body....  That is the main issue

Comment: How can i do this.. Have you any example ? Then Please show me.

Comment: **Try this code**

`try {
   
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());

   if (jsonObject.has("your tags")) {
   // Hnadle message
   // generate notification
   } 
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } `